# How to validate document before sending to the solr

Tags: solr, schema

In order to send bulk documents to solr I generate each document separately, make a post on a solr machine just to validate that document and then place the document in a Stream (Kafka, Kinesis or other). There is a consumer who reads this stream gathers the documents and bulk up the main solr cluster.
I would like to be able to validate this document without having to POST it in the first solr. Is there any way to validate that the generated document is compatible with my schema? This process of validating is making my indexing slow. And if I put an invalid document in the Stream, I will lose many documents in bulk.
Today I am using Solr 6 and I generate the documents in xml.
Thank you

Comment: Retrieve the schema and make sure that any required fields are present, and that the field types match? Or if you don't want to do that - you'll get an error when you're adding the batch - resubmit the first half of the batch, then the second - and see if you get any errors; then do that recursively. If your have 1k documents in your batches, 10 requests should give you at least one of the failing documents (or possibly more).

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to have two Solr collections running on the same server: the first would be your normal collection, and the second would be a "dummy" collection that you only use to test.

Then I'd send the docs, 1 at a time, to the dummy collection, see if Solr accepted it, and then if true, send to the full collection.  For the dummy collection, always send docs one at a time.  To be extra safe, you could even then query the dummy collection of that document (if there's some unique identifier available)

I do like MatsLindh answer as well, though I can imagine edge cases that would pass his test but still fail when they hit Solr, but still cool.